# Outlook Add-in that activates function when the user opens a email

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I'm creating an add-in that detects fraud in emails with in the body using AI. So I need run every time the user open an email. I didn't find anything on events. The Context add-in seems to not be usable in this scenario because of the dependency on regular expressions. I wanna know if someone knows another approach to this use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the feature of event based activation of add-ins in read mode, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [Tech Community Page](http://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions). Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when we go through our planning process. For more details on event based activation of add-ins you can read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch).

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to activate add-ins automatically for a selection without contextual conditions triggered (regex and etc.).