# OfficeJS: listen for an email selection

Tags: outlook, office-js

I am looking for a way to add a notification banner when the user selects an email in Outlook.
I've written a basic task pane OfficeJS admin but this requires the user to click an add-on button and keep the taskpane visible.

Is there a way to listen for such an event without requiring user (admin) interaction?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to get a task pane visible automatically for a selected item.

You can vote for such feature or suggest a new one at http://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the feature of event based activation of add-ins in read mode is not a part of the product. Please check answer on similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67823189/outlook-add-in-that-activates-function-when-the-user-opens-a-email) for more details.